# Swift - Mutate values of enum associate type properties

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I have a 2 structs conforming to one protocol. I created  enum with associated types as struct types. When I try to access properties of protocol type A using dynamicmember lookup, getters are working fine. But Set methods are throwing error: Key path with root type 'A' cannot be applied to a base of type 'A1'/'A2'

Sometimes I get this error as well: cannot assign through subscript: 'a' is immutable

```swift
import Foundation

protocol A {
    var id: String { get }
}

struct A1 : A {
    var id: String
    var type: String
}

struct A2 : A {
    var id: String
    var test: String
}

@dynamicMemberLookup
enum AType {
    case a1(A1)
    case a2(A2)
}

extension AType {
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<A, T>) -> T {
        get {
            switch self{
            case .a1(let a):
                return a[keyPath: keyPath]
            case .a2(let a):
                return a[keyPath: keyPath]
            }
        }

        set {
            switch self{
            case .a1(var a):
                a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
            case .a2(var a):
                a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}


let a1struct = A1(id: "123", type: "Test")
var atype = AType.a1(a1struct)

print(atype.id)
```

Any thoughts would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, probably a transcription bug, but `id` needs to be settable for this to make sense.

```
protocol A {
    var id: String { get set }  // <=== Add set
}
```

For the setter, there are two issues; one that is very clear, and the other a bit subtle. The clear issue is that even if this worked, it would do nothing:

```
        case .a1(var a):
            a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
```

This makes a copy of the associated data, then modifies that copy, then throws it away. What you need here is (though this code won't work either):

```
        case .a1(var a):
            a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
            self = .a1(a)
```

You need to modify `a` and then create a new enum value to hold it.

The more subtle problem is the type `WritableKeyPath<A, T>`. This says "a writable KeyPath rooted to something of type A." You mean "a writable KeyPath rooted to something of a type **which conforms** to A" which is not the same thing. For this code to work, the cases would need to be like `.a1(A)` rather than `.a1(A1)`.

Swift does allow you to read through a KeyPath that is rooted to a protocol the type conforms to. But it won't allow you to write through it. See [WritableKeyPath + inout argument of placeholder type doesn't compile](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8384) for a short discussion.

The way you would write "something that conforms to A" is:

```
subscript<Container: A, T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Container, T>) -> T {
```

However, that won't work because the type of Container is decided by the caller, and this would have to accept any A-conforming type passed (which you can't do).

I have not figured out how to fix this without an `as!` cast, but it can be done this way:

```
    set {
        switch self{
        case .a1(var a as A):
            a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
            self = .a1(a as! A1)
        case .a2(var a as A):
            a[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
            self = .a2(a as! A2)
        }
    }
```

(I probably would recommend reconsidering the use of an enum here, and see if you could just use A1 and A2 directly and use `is` rather than `switch` to distinguish them. Swift enums are often not as powerful as we'd like them to be compared to structs. But sometimes enums are still best.)

Comment: Thank Rob for the response. This really helped solve my issue